# LeetCode: Group Anagrams C#

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, strings, hash-map

[LeetCode: Group Anagrams C#](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/)
Given an array of strings, group anagrams together.

```
Example:

Input: ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"],
Output:
[
  ["ate","eat","tea"],
  ["nat","tan"],
  ["bat"]
]
```

Note:

All inputs will be in lowercase.
The order of your output does not matter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StringQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-medium/103/array-and-strings/778/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class GroupAnagramsTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string[] strs = {"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};
            var result = GroupAnagramsClass.GroupAnagrams(strs);
            List<IList<string>> expected = new List<IList<string>>();
            expected.Add( new List<string> {"eat", "tea", "ate"});
            expected.Add( new List<string> {"tan", "nat"});
            expected.Add( new List<string> {"bat"});
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected[i].ToList(), result[i].ToList());
            }
        }
    }

    public class GroupAnagramsClass
    {
        public static IList<IList<string>> GroupAnagrams(string[] strs)
        {
            Dictionary<char[], List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<char[], List<string>>(new CharComparer());
            foreach (var str in strs)
            {
                var key = str.ToCharArray();
                Array.Sort(key);
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out var temp))
                {
                    temp = dict[key] = new List<string>();
                }
                temp.Add(str);
            }

            List<IList<string>> res = new List<IList<string>>(dict.Values.ToList());
            return res;
        }
    }

    public class CharComparer : IEqualityComparer<char[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(char[] x, char[] y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (x.Length != y.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x[i] != y[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(char[] obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Please review for performance. 
I don't like me copying the dictionary into `IList<IList<string>`. Is there a better way to do so, considering this the desired API defined by the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Deriving from `IEqualityComparer` versus `EqualityComparer`.

The MSDN docs say the following:

> We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer interface, because the EqualityComparer class tests for equality using the IEquatable.Equals method instead of the Object.Equals method. This is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove methods of the Dictionary class and other generic collections.
>   <sub>[MSDN docs: IEqualityComparer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8)</sub>

## `Dictionary` versus `Lookup`

For grouping together objects from a sequence, where there might be a varying amount of items in each group, a `Lookup` is better than a `Dictionary`:

```
 var lookup = strs.ToLookup(key =>
 {
     var array = key.ToCharArray();
     Array.Sort(array);
     return array;
 }, new CharComparer());
 return lookup.Select(grouping => (IList<string>)grouping.ToList()).ToList();
```

## Comparing char-arrays

Since we're using `Linq`, let's use `Linq`:

```
public override bool Equals(char[] x, char[] y)
{
    if (x == null || y == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (x.Length != y.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return x.SequenceEqual(y);
}
```

The null behaviour is different and the length shortcut may stay, but the last loop we can offload to `Linq`.

## Hashcode

Both `Dictionary` and `Lookup` rely on the hashcode returned by the equalitycomparer to categorise the keys into bins. These bins is what allows these collections to get times in \$O(1)\$. Always returning the same value is going to cause problems when your inputs get bigger. It will effectively turn the collections into single arrays which have to be looped over to get to the correct key.

Creating good hashcodes is hard though, and I don't really know a good rule of thumb for creating them.

## `char[]` versus `string`

All in all, the hashcode and equalitycomparer is such a headache, it's probably easier, and more readable to convert the sorted `char[]` back into a `string`, and use that as the key for the lookup:

```
 var lookup = strs.ToLookup(key =>
 {
     var array = key.ToCharArray();
     Array.Sort(array);
     return new string(array);
 });
 return lookup.Select(grouping => (IList<string>)grouping.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you provide an interpretation of the comment from the MSDN? I can't understand it (having read the whole article and looked at the implementation); maybe you can enlighten me ;)  (ah, no, I think I've got it: they mean `EqualityComparer<T>` implements `IEqualityComparer` for you... but that's not what the text says at all)

Comment: @VisualMelon I must say, I am a bit puzzled too.

Comment: @VisualMelon The only advantage I see is that it performs some boilerplate null checks for us in _Equals(object x, object y)_ We only need to implement _Equals(T x, T y)_: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs. In addition, it also implements the non generic interface _IEqualityComparer_ making it possible to use your comparer in contra-variant situations.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for creating hashcodes is to use a co-prime pair and perform bit shifts and exclusive or's with them on immutable key data of your instance. It should also be very fast, 2 instances that are equal must have the same hashcode, and 2 instances with different hashcode cannot be equal. 2 instances that are not equal may or may not have the same hashcode.

Comment: @dfhwze "immutable" That's actually kinda tricky with these char-arrays. They are not explicitly immutable. They would be in this context (after  sorting them), but in that case we should make the comparer private and nest it within the class.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707347/preferring-equalitycomparert-to-iequalitycomparert

Comment: @JAD once the hashcode is used as a bucket in some hash set, the state should be immutable (at least the key state that determines the hashcode and therefore also equality).

Comment: Honestly, a lot of this bother can be avoided by converting the sorted `char[]` back into a string and using its equality and hashcode logic.

Answer (score 5):

I've reviewed another one of your question and there's a recurrent point I think needs to be addressed. Your usage of `IList`.

When you return something, you expect the user of your method to use it in a certain scope. Say I need a method to return all numbers between a certain range.

```
public IList<int> Range(int low, int high)
{
    // My C# is rusty, but if I remember correctly this works.
    return Enumerable.Range(low,high).ToList();
}

public void FooBar()
{
    var list = Range(0,10);

    //Why?
    list.Add(11);
}
```

This might not be a strong example, but my point is : `IList` represents a data structure where you can add, remove, replace elements and use the indexer. That's a lot of things, do the users of your method **need** all these things? No. By returning an `IList` you tell your users that the result is expected to be modified or accessed via an index, but they don't need this. You could use `ICollection`, which let's you add/remove/modifiy elements, without index access. Then again, do you want your users to do this? Probably not­. What I'd recommend is using `IEnumerable`. This states : Here's the "list" of things that you wanted, you can take a look, if you want to modify them change it to a list it's not my problem anymore.

The beauty of this changes is that you don't need to change anything in your code except for the return type of your `GroupAnagrams` method.

---

There's a bug in your equality checker, or at least an undocumented feature.

```
//Returns false, why?
CharComparer().Equals((char[])null, (char[])null);
```

The rest of the points I wanted to address have been touched by the other (great) reviews. But I want to stress **Never override `GetHashCode()` to `return 0` that's a bad idea.**

Comment: It is the API given by leetcode IList<>

Comment: @Gilad oh, I guess this makes sense. I think this would warrant a comment in your code, because otherwise everyone would wonder why you use this specific interface

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one liner to have a look at.

```
public static IList<IList<string>> GroupAnagrams(string[] strs)
{
    return strs.GroupBy(x => string.Concat(x.OrderBy(c => c))).Select(x => (IList<string>)x.ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.